# How to use smart_open to write a stream to a KMS-encrypted S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a stream to a KMS-encrypted S3 bucket using smart_open, but to no avail. Looking into the code of smart_open, there seems to be a test case for this, but I can't run it:

```
@_test_case
def test_s3_encrypted_file(benchmark, uri):
    text = 'с гранатою в кармане, с чекою в руке'
    s3_upload = {'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256'}
    actual = benchmark(write_read, uri, text, 'w', 'r', 'utf-8', s3_upload=s3_upload)
    assert actual == text
```

And I assumed this would work, but it just says s3_upload is not an option:

```
file = smart_open.open(url, 'w', transport_params={'session': session, s3_upload={'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms', 'SSEKMSKeyId': key}})
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this parameter has been [renamed recently](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/cf2bd8c105f8ffd5891351c7322932b4ef3db81c/MIGRATING_FROM_OLDER_VERSIONS.rst), so instead of `s3_upload` it is `multipart_upload_kwargs`.

I just got this working, per your example:

```
file = smart_open.open(url, 'w', transport_params={'session': session, 'multipart_upload_kwargs': {'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms', 'SSEKMSKeyId': key}})
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Note that this no longer works due to https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/develop/MIGRATING_FROM_OLDER_VERSIONS.rst

Comment: adding on @VlasSokolov it is now `transport_params={'client_kwargs': {  'S3.Client.create_multipart_upload': {'ServerSideEncryption':  'aws:kms', 'SSEKMSKeyId': key}}}`